# referencing object on default page from the master page vb file

Tags: .net, vb.net, master-pages

I have an asp image within my "default.aspx" page.

I set cookies on my masterpage vb file and depending on the cookie set, I want to show or hide this image.

default.aspx

```
<asp:image ImageUrl="/images/myimage.jpg" runat="server" ID="myimage" Visible="false"></asp:image>
```

mymaster.aspx.vb

```
Private Function getFreeCallNumber(ByVal value As String) As String
    Select Case value
        Case "MYCASE"
        myimage.visible = true
    End Select
End Function
```

I get the following error:

*'myimage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

Any ideas why, and more importantly, how to stop it??

Answer (score 0):

The master page doesn't have access to the content pages that use it. Since there are potentially many content pages using this master page, what would it mean for the master page to talk about `myimage`, when the actual content page is not `default.aspx` ?

If this image is intended to be *common to all pages that use this master page*, put it on the master page.

If you want each page to have a different image, create a `ContentPlaceHolder` on the master page and let the content pages put their image in there - then control the visibility of the `ContentPlaceHolder` from the master page codebehind.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. The problem is that I need to set the cookie on every page - hence it's in the master vb file. The image only needs to be visible on the one page though.